# Django ModelForm 'instance' param not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I am using Django's forms to validate API PATCH requests. In the "view" (which I use in quotes because it isn't really a view directly, it is a restless `Resource`, but that should be irrelevant here) which handles this patch request, `self.data` contains a dictionary of changes to some of the fields of the `License` object. I want to instantiate a `ModelForm` with the instance of the object to be changed. Clearly, though, I am misunderstanding how this works. See below:

```
def handle_patch(self, pk):
    license = License.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = LicenseResourceForm(self.data, instance=license)

    if not form.is_valid():
        print(form.errors)
```

If I pass a few fields as data to the above function, `form.errors` complains about every other required field of the `License` model, meaning I'm clearly not understanding how setting an instance on a `ModelForm` works.

I added a few debug prints to Django's `ModelForm` code itself in the `clean()` method, and as it begins to do the cleaning process, I can see that `self.instance` is populated with the instance of `License` that I expect, which confuses me - the `ModelForm` object knows the instance, but isn't using it to "fill in the blanks" so to speak.

So what am I misunderstanding? I must be doing this wrong.

**EDIT** I realize that some of you may want to see the `LicenseResourceForm` itself, so here it is, including my debug print:

```
class LicenseResourceForm(ModelForm):
    """Form for License Resource create and change endpoints."""
    class Meta(object):
        model = License
        fields = ['customer', 'service', 'enabled', 'not_valid_before', 'not_valid_after']

    def clean(self):
        try:
            print(self.instance)
            super().clean()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django forms aren't meant for API use and don't understand PATCH semantics. They are meant for the workflow of a user entering or changing data in a web form, which will always post all the data to the backend. Therefore, all fields listed in the `fields` attribute of the form will be checked against the data, and any missing fields will be validated as blank.

You could probably fix this by doing something clever to dynamically set the list of fields based on the data supplied, but really you should use the appropriate tool for validating your data. I don't know restless, but django-rest-framework has serializers which can be used for this.

Comment: Thinking about it in the context of HTML forms and the fact that they would never send a partial form makes sense. And good idea about the dynamic setting of fields. I'll play around with it. Thank you!